# Calculating the confidence interval for population variance given the confidence interval for population mean

Tags: statistics, variance, confidence-interval

I am given a sample size of 9 from a normal population, as well as the 95% confidence interval for population mean. I want to calculate the 95% population variance.

I see that the confidence interval for an unknown population mean is $\overline{Y}\pm t_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$. Then since the midpoint of the confidence interval for population mean is the sample mean, I can plug that into $\overline{Y}$, 9 into $n$, and 0.025 into $\alpha$. From there, I can solve for $S$. How can I find the confidence interval for population variance from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A two-sided interval for the variance is
$$\left[\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\chi_{1 - \alpha/2, n-1}^2}, \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\chi_{\alpha/2, n-1}^2}\right]$$ where $S^2$ is the sample variance, $n$ is the sample size, and $\chi_{\alpha/2, n-1}^2$ is the $\alpha/2$ quantile of the chi-square distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom; i.e., it is the value at which the CDF of a $\chi_{n-1}^2$ random variable equals $\alpha/2$; similarly, $\chi_{1-\alpha/2, n-1}^2$ is the $1 - \alpha/2$ quantile.

For example, with $n = 9$ and $\alpha = 0.05$, we have $$\chi_{0.025, 8}^2 \approx 2.17973, \\ \chi_{0.975, 8}^2 \approx 17.5345.$$  Notice that because these are in the denominators of the confidence limits, the larger quantile is used for the *lower* confidence limit, and the smaller quantile is used for the *upper* confidence limit.

Comment: Using the S that I calculated from the first equation, I can plug it in to this expression right? I saw this equation but didn't put the two and two together.

Comment: @bunny Yes.  They are the same thing.